# Get UnitsSold for Today, Same day last week and same day last year

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to build a multiple subquery query so that I can databind the results to a chart

This is my current query:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT Sum(DBO.ORDERLINE.QTY)               AS UnitsSold, 
                         { fn HOUR(dbo.[Order].PaymentDate) } AS MyHour 
FROM   DBO.[ORDER] 
       INNER JOIN DBO.ORDERLINE 
               ON DBO.[ORDER].ORDERID = DBO.ORDERLINE.ORDERID 
WHERE  ( DBO.[ORDER].WEBSITEID = 2 ) 
       AND ( DBO.[ORDER].ORDERSTATUSID = 2 ) 
       AND ( Day(DBO.[ORDER].PAYMENTDATE) = 01 ) 
       AND ( Month(DBO.[ORDER].PAYMENTDATE) = 08 ) 
       AND ( Year(DBO.[ORDER].PAYMENTDATE) = 2013 ) 
GROUP  BY { fn HOUR(dbo.[Order].PaymentDate) }
```

This brings back two columns, UnitsSold and MyHour based on yesterdays data - this works great..

However I want to also get that same data for the same day last week, and the same day last year, I can provide the MONTH/DAY/YEAR values myself via c# - I'm just not sure how to do this complicated query.

Let me know if you need any more info.

Thanks,

Michael

Comment: In case anyone else was wondering like me, the "{ fn }" commands are ODBC functions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630290.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly your question, you want just one query with 3 results.

You could use a [`union all`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx).

This will combine the 3 queries with the different date intervals.
You will get back one resultset with 3 rows.

**UPDATE**

You could combine the queries like this (not tested, not at my pc)

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT Sum(DBO.ORDERLINE.QTY) AS UnitsSold, { fn HOUR(dbo.[Order].PaymentDate) } AS MyHour 
FROM   DBO.[ORDER] 
       INNER JOIN DBO.ORDERLINE 
               ON DBO.[ORDER].ORDERID = DBO.ORDERLINE.ORDERID 
WHERE  ( DBO.[ORDER].WEBSITEID = 2 ) 
       AND ( DBO.[ORDER].ORDERSTATUSID = 2 ) 
       AND ( Day(DBO.[ORDER].PAYMENTDATE) = 01 ) 
       AND ( Month(DBO.[ORDER].PAYMENTDATE) = 08 ) 
       AND ( Year(DBO.[ORDER].PAYMENTDATE) = 2013 ) 
GROUP  BY { fn HOUR(dbo.[Order].PaymentDate) } 

union all

SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT Sum(DBO.ORDERLINE.QTY) AS UnitsSold, { fn HOUR(dbo.[Order].PaymentDate) } AS MyHour 
FROM   DBO.[ORDER] 
       INNER JOIN DBO.ORDERLINE 
               ON DBO.[ORDER].ORDERID = DBO.ORDERLINE.ORDERID 
WHERE  ( DBO.[ORDER].WEBSITEID = 2 ) 
       AND ( DBO.[ORDER].ORDERSTATUSID = 2 ) 
       AND ( Day(DBO.[ORDER].PAYMENTDATE) = 24 ) 
       AND ( Month(DBO.[ORDER].PAYMENTDATE) = 07 ) 
       AND ( Year(DBO.[ORDER].PAYMENTDATE) = 2013 ) 
GROUP  BY { fn HOUR(dbo.[Order].PaymentDate) } 

union all

SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT Sum(DBO.ORDERLINE.QTY) AS UnitsSold, { fn HOUR(dbo.[Order].PaymentDate) } AS MyHour 
FROM   DBO.[ORDER] 
       INNER JOIN DBO.ORDERLINE 
               ON DBO.[ORDER].ORDERID = DBO.ORDERLINE.ORDERID 
WHERE  ( DBO.[ORDER].WEBSITEID = 2 ) 
       AND ( DBO.[ORDER].ORDERSTATUSID = 2 ) 
       AND ( Day(DBO.[ORDER].PAYMENTDATE) = 01 ) 
       AND ( Month(DBO.[ORDER].PAYMENTDATE) = 08 ) 
       AND ( Year(DBO.[ORDER].PAYMENTDATE) = 2012 ) 
GROUP  BY { fn HOUR(dbo.[Order].PaymentDate) }
```

You will get 3 rows with your data. If you want you can also add a fake columon saying wich is what (today, lastweek, last year) for the chart

Comment: This answer is too brief. Provide more details on how to solve the problem and maybe show an example too.

Comment: Could you please elaborate and give examples?

Comment: this works, but not the in the way i expected it, or maybe I explained it wrong. But I need the 3 seperate data in their own rows / columns..

So for instance:
`MyHour UnitsToday UnitsLastWeek UnitsLastYear
0      6          4             5
1      6          4             5
2      6          4             5
4      6          4             5`

Comment: I think you should use subqueries than. Personally I will go with my solutions adding a column to know what represent every row.

Comment: Can you give me an example of what you mean by 'adding a custom column' ?

Comment: in your select you simply add a value (integer or string, what you prefer to handle) Cast('Today' as varchar) as type in the first, Cast('Last Week' as varchar) in the second, etc

Answer (score 4):

The [NRF Retail Calendar](http://www.nrf.com/modules.php?name=Pages&sp_id=391) was created specifically to address the business problem of sales comparatives - **the retail industry has solved this problem in the 1930's** by standardizing the calendar into a "4-5-4" calendar, where the first month of each trimester has 4 weeks, second has 5 weeks, third has 4, makes 52 weeks in 4 quarters, with 364 days per year. And they addressed this other problem by periodically making 53-week years - [more details here, quote below](http://www.nrf.com/modules.php?name=Pages&sp_id=392)). It accounts for leap years, and ensures a Friday is always compared to a Friday.

> **What is the purpose of the 4-5-4 Calendar?**
>
> The 4-5-4 Calendar serves as a voluntary guide for the retail industry and ensures sales comparability between years by dividing the year into months based on a 4 weeks – 5 weeks – 4 weeks format. The layout of the calendar lines up holidays and ensures the same number of Saturdays and Sundays in comparable months. Hence, like days are compared to like days for sales reporting purposes.

## Step 1: Set it up

By modeling this calendar into some `dbo.RetailTime` table, you make it much easier to compare sales from the correct dates - `TY week 26 day 6` compares to `LY week 26 day 6`, **whichever actual calendar dates that was**. The calendar is an *abstraction* of the concept of *time*.

Something like this:

```
public interface IRetailTime
{
    DateTime Date { get; } // does not have "time" info ("00:00:00")
    int DayHour { get; }
    int WeekDay { get; }
    int YearWeek { get; }
    int YearMonth { get; }
    int YearQuarter { get; }
    int Year { get; }
}
```

You could flesh this up further by adding fields `QuarterDay`, `QuarterWeek`, `QuarterMonth`, `MonthDay`, and `MonthWeek`, depending on your reporting needs. Retailers typically concanenate the `Year` with the `YearWeek` to identify each calendar week, so week 26 of year 2013 would be "201326".

Then you write a script to import the NRF calendar data into your model, and you can create a function, stored procedure, view or whatever, to give you the `RetailTimeId` for `LY` and, heck why not, for `LLY` (2 years ago) fields (which could both be null) for each `Id` in your calendar table.

The result gives you something like this (below assumes hour-level granularity, with 24 hours per day):

```
    RetailTimeId   LYId   LLYId
               1    NULL   NULL
               2    NULL   NULL
             ...     ...    ...
            8737       1   NULL
            8738       2   NULL
             ...     ...    ...
           17472    8737      1
           17473    8738      2
             ...     ...    ...
```

This gives you a lookup table (persisting it to an actual `dbo.RetailTimeLookup` table doesn't hurt) with an `Id` for LY & LLY, for each Id in your `dbo.RetailTime` table (`RetailTimeId`). You'll want a unique index on the `RetailTimeId` column, but not on the other two, because of 53-week years, where you'll probably want to compare the 53rd week against the 1st week of that same year.

## Step 2: Correlate with your sales data

The next step is to lookup the `Id` that corresponds to your `PaymentDate`, by matching the "date" part (without the "time" part) with `RetailTime.Date` and the "time" part (well just the hour) with `RetailTime.DayHour`. **This can be an expensive operation**, you may prefer having a scheduled overnight process (ETL) that will populate a "SalesInfo" data table with the `RetailTimeId` for the `PaymentDate` already looked up, so with sales your data formatted like this:

```
public interface ISalesInfo
{
    int RetailTimeId { get; }
    int UnitsSold { get; }
}
```

All that's missing is a join with the TY/LY/LLY lookup view from above, and you can now "slice" your sales figures across a "time" dimension - I used to have a *view* for *this year sales* and another for *last year sales* at the lowest granularity level, like this:

```
CREATE VIEW vwSALES_TY AS
BEGIN

    SELECT t.Id RetailTimeId,
           t.Year, 
           t.YearQuarter, 
           t.YearMonth, 
           t.YearWeek, 
           t.WeekDay, 
           t.DayHour,
           sales.UnitsSold Units                -- total units sold
           --,sales.CostAmount CostAmount       -- cost value of sold units
           --,sales.RetailAmount RetailAmount   -- full-price value of sold units
           --,sales.CurrentAmount CurrentAmount -- actual sale value of sold units
    FROM dbo.RetailTime t
        INNER JOIN dbo.SalesInfo sales ON t.Id = sales.RetailTimeId
    WHERE t.Year = 2013

END

CREATE VIEW vwSALES_LY AS
BEGIN

    SELECT t.Id RetailTimeId,
           t.Year, 
           t.YearQuarter, 
           t.YearMonth, 
           t.YearWeek, 
           t.WeekDay, 
           t.DayHour,
           sales.UnitsSold Units                -- total units sold
           --,sales.CostAmount CostAmount       -- cost value of sold units
           --,sales.RetailAmount RetailAmount   -- full-price value of sold units
           --,sales.CurrentAmount CurrentAmount -- actual sale value of sold units
    FROM dbo.RetailTime t
        INNER JOIN dbo.SalesInfo sales ON t.Id = sales.RetailTimeId
    WHERE t.Year = 2012

END
```

> **The *meaning* of numbers**
>
> I put *CostAmount*, *RetailAmount* and *CurrentAmount* in there because from a business standpoint, knowing units sold is good, but it doesn't tell you how profitable those sales were - you might have sold twice as many units LY, if you gave them away at a high discount, your gross margin (GM%) might have been very slim or even negative, and selling half as many units TY might turn out to be a much, much better situation... if inventory is turning at a healthy rate - every single bit of information is related with another, one way or another.
>
> GM% is `(1-CostAmount/CurrentAmount)*100` - that's the profitability figure every *suit* needs to know. %Discount is `(1-CurrentAmount/RetailAmount)*100` - that's how discounted your sales were. A "units sold" figure alone doesn't tell much; there's a saying in the Retail World that goes "*Sales is for vanity, profits for sanity*". But I'm drifting. The idea is to include as much information as possible in your granular sales data - and that does include product (ideal is a SKU), point of sale and even client info, if that's available. Anything that's missing can never make it onto a report.

## Step 3: ...Profit!

With a *view* that gives you TY sales and another that gives you LY sales ready to be lined-up, all that's left to do is *ask the database*:

```
SELECT t.Year, 
       t.YearQuarter, 
       t.YearMonth, 
       t.YearWeek, 
       t.WeekDay, 
       t.DayHour,
       SUM(ISNULL(ty.Units,0)) UnitsTY,
       SUM(ISNULL(ly.Units,0)) UnitsLY
FROM dbo.RetailTime t
    INNER JOIN dbo.RetailTimeLookup lookup ON t.Id = lookup.RetailTimeId
    LEFT JOIN dbo.vwSALES_TY ty ON lookup.RetailTimeId = ty.RetailTimeId
    LEFT JOIN dbo.vwSALES_LY ly ON lookup.LYId = ly.RetailTimeId
WHERE t.Year = 2013
```

Now this will give you TY vs LY for each hour of each day of retail calendar year 2013 (preserving 2012 history where there's not yet a record in 2013), but that's not yet exactly what you want, although all the information is already there.

If you took the above and *selected into* a temporary table (or used it as a sub-query), you would need to do something like this in order to fetch only the figures you're interested in:

```
SELECT t.DayHour,
       SUM(lw.UnitsTY) LastWeekUnitsTY,
       SUM(lw.UnitsLY) LastWeekUnitsLY,
       SUM(tw.UnitsTY) ThisWeekUnitsTY,
       SUM(tw.UnitsLY) ThisWeekUnitsLY
FROM (SELECT DayHour FROM #above GROUP BY DayHour) t
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT UnitsTY, UnitsLY 
               FROM #above 
               WHERE YearWeek = 25 AND WeekDay = 6) lw 
        ON t.DayHour = lw.DayHour
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT UnitsTY, UnitsLY 
               FROM #above 
               WHERE YearWeek = 26 AND WeekDay = 6) tw
        ON t.DayHour = tw.DayHour
GROUP BY t.DayHour
```

...But this would be comparing only the sales of the Friday. If you wanted to calculate a week-to-date (WTD) amount that lines up against the previous year, you would simply replace `WeekDay = 6` with `WeekDay <= 6` in both `WHERE` clauses. That's why I put `SUM`s and a `GROUP BY`.

> **Note**
>
> The %variance between TY and LY is `(TY/LY - 1) * 100`. If you have more than a single point of sale (/store), you may have fewer stores LY than TY and that thwarts the comparison. Retailers have addressed this other problem with *door-for-door* %variances, often referred to as "*comp* increase". This is achieved by not only lining up ***When*** (the "time" dimension), but also ***Where*** (the "store" dimension), only accounting for stores that were opened LY, ignoring "*non-comp stores*". For reports that break figures down a *product hierarchy*, the ***What*** also requires a join with some *product* data.

## One last thing

The idea is to **compare apples with apples** - there's a reason why you need to pull these numbers: every retailer wants to know whether they're improving over LY figures. Anyone can divide two numbers and come up with a percentage figure. Unfortunately in the real-life business world, reporting *accurate* data is not always *that* simple.

Disclaimer: I have worked 9 years in the retail industry.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the supplied values as parts of a date, if you combine them into a properly cast `DATE` variable you can use `DATEADD()`:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT Sum(DBO.ORDERLINE.QTY)               AS UnitsSold, 
                         { fn HOUR(dbo.[Order].PaymentDate) } AS MyHour 
FROM   DBO.[ORDER] 
       INNER JOIN DBO.ORDERLINE 
               ON DBO.[ORDER].ORDERID = DBO.ORDERLINE.ORDERID 
WHERE  ( DBO.[ORDER].WEBSITEID = 2 ) 
       AND ( DBO.[ORDER].ORDERSTATUSID = 2 ) 
       AND ( DBO.[ORDER].PAYMENTDATE = @date 
              OR DBO.[ORDER].PAYMENTDATE = Dateadd(WEEK, -1, @date) 
              OR DBO.[ORDER].PAYMENTDATE = Dateadd(YEAR, -1, @date) ) 
GROUP  BY { fn HOUR(dbo.[Order].PaymentDate) }
```

Also keep in mind that if you've got `DATETIME` as your data type on either end of the equation you'd want to `CAST` them as `DATE` to ignore the `TIME` portion.

Comment: Thanks! Would YEAR, -1, @date give me the Friday 3rd august 2012 if I used todays date? Also, when using "DECLARE /@date datetime = '01/07/2013'" I get no results, am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Try `DECLARE @date DATE = '20130701'`  `YYYYMMDD`, for a year back it would be the same date, August 02, 2013 -1 year = August 02, 2012.  There are adjustments you can make to get the closest friday a year back if desired.